# Jenkins listens on weird ports

Tags: port, jenkins

I use `Centos 6.5` and `Jenkins 1.547`. [I installed Jenkins as outlined in Jenkins's wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+RedHat+distributions).

I configured Jenkins to listen on local port `8081`.

`netstat -tulpn` reveals that Jenkins additionally listens on more ports (*PID 981* being the running Jenkins process):

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep 981

tcp        0      0 :::41613                    :::*                        LISTEN      981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8081       :::*                        LISTEN      981/java
tcp        0      0 :::43586                    :::*                        LISTEN      981/java
udp        0      0 :::33848                    :::*                                    981/java
udp        0      0 :::5353                     :::*                                    981/java
```

I am wondering about the purpose of those additional ports. Also, these ports are reachable from the outside, i.e. an outside `nmap` scan shows these ports being open.

How can I configure Jenkins to only listen on local port 8081?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[There is an open issue in Jenkin's bugtracker which outlines the steps to follow in order to close all undesired ports](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12731):

- In Jenkins' web interface, under *Dashboard* → *Manage Jenkins* → ***Configure System*** → *SSH Server*, select ***Disable***.
- In Jenkins' web interface, under *Dashboard* → *Manage Jenkins* → ***Configure Global Security*** → *TCP port for JNLP slave agents*, select ***Disable***.
- Assuming Jenkins starts up via `/etc/init.d/jenkins` as an [**unprivileged** user](http://www.jpluscplusm.com/blog/2013/01/23/securing-jenkins-behind-an-nginx-reverse-proxy/), then edit the configuration file `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`, locate `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS` and add `-Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -Dhudson.udp=1023` (... e.g. assuming it currently reads `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"`, then change it to `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -Dhudson.udp=1023"`)

Comment: The [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) recommend to set `-Dhudson.udp=-1` to disable UDP multicast. Setting `-Dhudson.udp=1023` does the trick only if the jenkins instance does not have root privileges.